# Как работает Integer.compare?

Tags: java

Программа кошачья битва.
Суть в том, что создаём объекты класса `Cat`, задаём аргументы и на основе этих аргументов сравниваем, кто победит. Всё понятно, кроме того, как работает **Integer.compare**.
Все аргументы двух котов, которые мы сравниваем, сохраняем в одну переменную `int score`, и я не могу понять, как по данным из одной переменной мы узнаем, что, допустим, `cat2` слабее `cat1`?

```
public boolean fight(Cat anotherCat) {
  int ageScore = Integer.compare(this.age, anotherCat.age);
  int weightScore = Integer.compare(this.weight, anotherCat.weight);
  int strengthScore = Integer.compare(this.strength, anotherCat.strength);

  int score = ageScore + weightScore + strengthScore;
  return score > 0; // return score > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Я понимаю если бы мы сравнивали аргументы `cat1` и `cat2` и вносили в две разные переменные, допустим:

```
public boolean fight(Cat anotherCat) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  if (this.weight > anotherCat.weight) i++;
  else if (this.weight != anotherCat.weight) j++;

  if (this.age > anotherCat.age) i++;
  else if (this.age != anotherCat.age) j++;

  if (this.strength > anotherCat.strength) i++;
  else if (this.strength != anotherCat.strength) j++;
}
```

Весь код программы:

```
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat cat1 = new Cat("Dana Wait", 5, 2, 2);
    Cat cat2 = new Cat("Habib", 4, 3, 4);
    Cat cat3 = new Cat("Mac Gregor", 6, 5, 3);

    System.out.println(cat1.fight(cat2));
    System.out.println(cat2.fight(cat3));
    System.out.println(cat1.fight(cat3));
  }

  public static class Cat {
    protected String name;
    protected int age;
    protected int weight;
    protected int strength;

    public Cat(String name, int age, int weight, int strength) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.weight = weight;
      this.strength = strength;
    }

    public boolean fight(Cat anotherCat) {
      int ageScore = Integer.compare(this.age, anotherCat.age);
      int weightScore = Integer.compare(this.weight, anotherCat.weight);
      int strengthScore = Integer.compare(this.strength, anotherCat.strength);

      int score = ageScore + weightScore + strengthScore;
      return score > 0; // return score > 0 ? true : false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)

Comment: Выдержка из документации: "Parameters:
x - the first int to compare, 
y - the second int to compare.
Returns: 
the value 0 if x == y; a value less than 0 if x < y; and a value greater than 0 if x > y"

Comment: Но, мы же передаем итог сравниваемых аргументов в переменные ageScore, weightScore, strengthScore, в этих переменных аргументы могут быть и cat1 и cat2. А потом суммируем их в переменной score. как мы узнаём что cat1 сильнее cat2, если в переменной score аргументы и того и другого, и мы их складываем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Как работает [Integer.compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int))?

Открываем класс `Integer` и смотрим метод `compare`:

```java
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Для наглядности этот код можно переписать так:

```java
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    if (x < y) {
        return -1;
    } else if (x == y) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

т. е. метод `compare` сравнивает два числа между собой и возвращает:

- `-1` - первое число меньше второго
- `0` - числа равны
- `1` - первое число больше второго

Answer (score 2):

Давайте постараюсь объяснить.

```
int ageScore = Integer.compare(this.age, anotherCat.age);
```

Что тут сравнивается и каков результат? Сравниваются значения `age` у двух котов. Если первый больше, то результат равен 1, если равен, то 0 и если меньше, то -1.
Отсюда следует, что `ageScore` может быть -1, либо 0, либо 1.
Итак по 3 параметрам котов.

Итоговый счёт ведётся по сумме трёх раундов по параметрам.
И если сумма `score > 0` то кот (`this`) сильнее.

Answer (score 0):

Тут сравнение реализовано таким образом, что переменная `score` меньше нуля, если кот представленный `this` слабее, равна нулю, если сила такая же и больше нуля, если сильнее.

То есть в альтернативной реализации вы бы сравнивали `i` и `j`, а тут нужно сравнивать `score` с нулем, имеем соответствие:

```
i ? j  |  score ? 0
=======+============
i > j  |  score > 0
i == j |  score == 0
i < j  |  score < 0
```

У вас каждое сравнение дает плюс 1 тому кто сильнее, и это точно то, что возвращает `Integer.compare`. Кто сильнее - тому 1, если равны - 0.